# IIS remote virtual directory anonymous access

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-directory, anonymous-access

I have two servers. One is static image host and other is public web server. I need to use shared folder from static server as usual folder in web server with create/read/write/delete things.
I've created public network share on first server with specific login/pass access, created same user on second server and changed pool identity to it, mapped virtual directory to that remote shared folder.

**Problem:** Accesing images in virtual folder works for logged users, but leads to login page for anonymous users. And only that one specific virtual folder does that! Content from all siblings can be accessed by anonumous users.

I have that setting in site's root web.config without any specific location

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

I have web.config files with that content in shared folder on static server and in parent folder where virtual folder is located.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Also "IIS/Authentication/Anonymous Authentication" is enabled in IIS features for that folder, its parent folder and whole site.

Web server is Windows Server 2012 R2 and site is MVC3 based.